# How to use Replace function in a custom script?

Tags: pyqgis, replace, qgis-modeler

I would like to use *Replace* function in a QGIS model but it doesn't work as I wish. I was working with Joseph's brilliant solution (using a custom script in a model) but I couldn't find out how to replace a specific character in a field. I would like to replace every '\' in Fromfield with '/' and write the result into Tofield.
I tried this and a few more, but nothing:

```
##Test=name
##Layer=vector
##Tofield=Field Layer
##Fromfield=Field Layer

from qgis.core import QgsExpression

layer = processing.getObject(Layer)  
layer.startEditing()

idx = layer.fieldNameIndex(Tofield)
g= str(Fromfield)
e = QgsExpression(g.replace("\\","/"))
e.prepare(layer.pendingFields())

for f in layer.getFeatures():
    f[idx] = e.evaluate(f)
    layer.updateFeature(f)

layer.commitChanges()
```

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the same syntax like in field calculator of QGIS (FC). From python there is a little hack you have to do. The working function in FC is:

`replace("from_field", '\\' , '/')`

From python, using `QgsExpression`, you will escape twice the backslash char, so the new function becomes:

`'replace("' + Fromfield + '", \'\\\\\' ,\'/\')'`

Your code should to work as follow:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsExpression

layer = processing.getObject(Layer)  
layer.startEditing()

idx_to = layer.fieldNameIndex(Tofield)
e = QgsExpression(u'replace("' + Fromfield + '", \'\\\\\' ,\'/\')')
e.prepare(layer.pendingFields())

for f in layer.getFeatures():
    f[idx_to] = e.evaluate(f)
    layer.updateFeature(f)

layer.commitChanges()
```

Also, you can use only python here, without the QGIS API, with the following code:

```py
layer = processing.getObject(Layer)  
layer.startEditing()

idx_to = layer.fieldNameIndex(Tofield)
idx_from = layer.fieldNameIndex(Fromfield)

for f in layer.getFeatures():
    f[idx_to] = f[idx_from].replace('\\' ,'/')
    layer.updateFeature(f)

layer.commitChanges()
```

Hope this helps!